# Read Array name using JsonSlurper

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

I am new to the groovy language

I am trying to parse a JSON file using JsonSlurper in a groovy script. How can I access the names of the arrays in the JSON file below? i.e Array1 and Array2? And also so far I have only tried to declare a list using findall, but how do I declare the list without a condition?

```
def input = new JsonSlurper().parse(reader)
def items = input.Order.Items.findAll { item -> item.Valid == "true"}
```

Input:

```
{
  "Order": {
    "Header": {
      "OrderNumber": "ORD60001",
      "Date": "20190218"
    },
    "Array1": [
      {
        "ItemNumber": "10",
        "MaterialNumber": "MT70001",
        "Quantity": 57,
        "Valid": true
      },
      {
        "ItemNumber": "20",
        "MaterialNumber": "MT80001",
        "Quantity": 28,
        "Valid": false
      }
    ],
    "Array2": [
      {
        "ItemNumber": "10",
        "MaterialNumber": "MT70001",
        "Quantity": 57,
        "Valid": true
      },
      {
        "ItemNumber": "20",
        "MaterialNumber": "MT80001",
        "Quantity": 28,
        "Valid": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "Order": {
        "Header": {
            "OrderNumber": "ORD60001",
            "Date": "20190218"
        },
        "Array1": [
            {
                "ItemNumber": "10",
                "MaterialNumber": "MT70001",
                "Quantity": 57,
                "Valid": true
            }
        ],
        "Array2": [
            {
                "ItemNumber": "10",
                "MaterialNumber": "MT70001",
                "Quantity": 57,
                "Valid": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `input.Order.keySet()`

Comment: Thank you, I am having a hard time figuring out how to declare the list, I am used to the Gpath but since the name is dynamic i.e. Array1, Array2 how can I declare the array list instead of the static   def items = input.Order.Items.findAll { item -> item.Valid == "true"} where "Items" is the name of the key?

Comment: Maybe you could add what result you expect from the shown input?

Comment: I realize that i may need to use the findall but still no success. I added the expected output. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I see now...

You probably want something more like this:

```
def filtered = [
    Order: new JsonSlurper().parse(reader)
               .Order
               .entrySet()
               .collectEntries {
                   it.value instanceof List ?
                       [it.key, it.value.findAll { it.Valid }] :
                       it
               }
]
​println new JsonBuilder(filtered).toPrettyString()
```

#### Edit for the new structure:

```
def validArrayEntries = input.Order.entrySet().findResults { entry ->
    // Go through all the orders, and find the ones that are lists
    if (entry.value instanceof List) {

        // Count the number of ones that are Valid
        def validEntries = entry.value.count { it.Valid }

        // If there are valid entries, then keep only them
        if (validEntries > 0) {
            [(entry.key): entry.value.findAll { it.Valid }]
        }
    }
}.collectEntries() // This collects them back into a map

// Then we can define our required JSON model               
def model = [
    PurchaseOrder: [
        HeaderData: [ ID:  input.Order.Header.OrderNumber ],

        // And this injects the map from above into this map
        *:validArrayEntries
    ]
]

def builder = new JsonBuilder(model).toPrettyString()
```

I've commented the code, and tried to make it understandable, please let me know if it needs more explanation

Comment: I was having challenges understanding this. I need to modify the fields in the output too it turns out.  I had success using a for loop (see code above) but not sure what delegate does, once I added it, the code worked.

Comment: @EricC. I've updated my answer, let me know if it doesn't make sense 

Comment: i added a count so we skip arrays with no valid entries

Comment: i think i got it. great explanation

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the name of any property of the Order object which contains a "Valid: true" element, you can do:

```
def entriesContainingOneValidChild = input.Order.entrySet()
    .findAll { item -> item.value.Valid?.any() }.key
```